# Insert 120 second wait in Visual studio Webtest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, webtest

I want to add a delay of 120 second between the execution of two web requests. I have tried using think time but it won't pause the execution for 120 sec.

Can anyone please let me know how to add wait to pause the execution for 120 second (after say 2 web request execution) and then proceed the execution for next request.

I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Could you post your code? Maybe `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 120)` solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think times are processed **after** the response is received. So to have a delay between two requests set the think time on the first request. I have successfully used long sleep times. Think times can be disabled in a test so make sure they are enabled:

1 In the ".testsettings" file, in the **Web test** section.

2 In the **Think profile** property of the scenario. If the delay should be (as near as possible to) exactly 120 seconds then set the profile to `On`.

3 The default for when Visual Studio runs a standalone web test is to not use think times. Thus everything runs as fast as possible. The setting in (1) above can be used to change the default. A temporary change to the default can be made from the "Edit test settings" command of the web test results window; this change only applies to test runs started by the "Click here to run again" in the same window.

If the two requests are actually different web tests then the **Think time between test iterations** property of the scenario may be useful.

Do not use any of the task or thread `delay` (or `sleep`) methods if there is any chance that this test will be used as part of a load test as they will stop many virtual users from running. See the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36351280/546871) for a fuller explanation. A `delay` or `sleep` call might be used if the web test will **never** be used within a load test.

Comment: You were right @AdrianHHH . Changing the ".testsetting" file in webtest worked for me. And as per your instruction I have removed Thread.sleep from my code.  **Go to local.testsetting > webtest > check the checkbox "Silmulate think times", click on apply and click close**. This solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this

```
 Thread.Sleep(Number_Second);
```

Comment: This could do with a bit of expansion on where to put this code? But - without any code being shown in the first place - a bit of a hard question to answer.

Comment: Thank you. System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000); worked for me.

Comment: Please be very careful in using this method within a Visual Studio web test, for the reasons I wrote in my answer to this question.